# How to create a new debug marker with icon for eclipse error view?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I write a custom logger with eclipse `StatuManager` and I want to write an API to log `debug` information with an icon in eclipse error view.

how could I create a custom marker and attach it to IStatus object so this Status show in Eclipse Error view?
i tried `annotationTypes` and explore `IMarker` API.
Please suggest some idea or any reference point.

Comment: If you mean the Problems view that displays `IMarker` objects only so you must use a marker.

Comment: not in problem view. i want to create a custom marker with icon and show them in eclipse error view. whenever a debug message logged.

Comment: What error view? There is no view called that in my Eclipse install.

Comment: It's Eclipse Error Log view.

Answer (score 0):

The Error Log view shows data written to the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory  using the logging APIs.

You can write an `IStatus` object to the log using something like:

```java
IStatus status = new Status(....);

Activator.getLog().log(status);
```

where `Activator` is your plugin's activator extending `Plugin` or `AbstractUIPlugin`.

If you don't have an activator or it doesn't extend those classes you can use:

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());

Platform.getLog(bundle).log(status);
```

Comment: I already implement this in my custom logger. what I want here is to show a custom icon for debug message.  I introduce different API  like error(), info(), debug() etc for logger which internal call eclipse platform logging functionality.

i want to log debug message using above code and show custom icon to this message in Error log view.

currently in eclipse log view we can see only  ERROR, INFO  & WARN messages with icon.

Comment: You can't. The error log view does not provide any customization.